# Как дополнительный текст над заголовком?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Никак не получается сделать также - предложите свои варианты.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо добавить линии над и под заголовком, а так же над ним добавить мини-текст

Comment: " предложите свои варианты" --- да, согласен,  предложите свои варианты!

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По вот такому принципе можно. Можно не в стили складывать текст, а span внутри сделать и то же самое.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

h2:before {
  content: 'над заголовком';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 7px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
```